# Heterogenous weighted geometric mean in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to calculate a weighted geometric mean in python(the product of a group of numbers(f) raised to '1/f'). I am using tkinter messagebox to build a gui. I have created a dictionary of key:value pairs. The keys are arbitrary. The values are the inputs of the geometric mean calculation. I have defined 'a' as the product of nine variables(f). I have assigned 'b' a value of '1/9' as the 1/f, the number of variables. However, I am trying to make the function heterogeneous. So that it can change the value of b, depending on the number of variables(f). For example, if 'a' has 5 variables, then b should = '1/5'. What would a heterogeneous geometric mean function look like in python?

```
mydict = {'good':0.7, 'average':0.5, 'optimal': 1, 'unacceptable': 0, 'major innovation': 1, 'minor innovation': 0.7, 'no innovation': 0.4, '1st lowest': 1, '2nd lowest': 0.7, '3rd lowest': 0.5, '4th lowest': 0.3}
a = float( mydict[label9] ) * float( mydict[label9] ) * float( mydict[label9] ) *float( mydict[label10] ) * float( mydict[label11] ) *float( mydict[label12] ) * float( mydict[label13] ) * float( mydict[label13] ) * float( mydict[label14]) 
b = 1/9
c = a**b


    # Widgets:
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
label1 = Label(window, text = 'Bid Number', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label2 = Label(window, text = 'Cost Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label3 = Label(window, text = 'Past Performance', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label4 = Label(window, text = 'Quality Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label5 = Label(window, text = 'Management Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label6 = Label(window, text = 'Innovation Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label7 = Label(window, text = 'Compliance Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label8 = Label(window, text = 'Bid 1' , relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label9 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label10 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label11 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label12 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label13 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label14 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label15 = Label(window, text = 'Bid Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label16 = Label(window, text = c, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
button1 = Button(window, text = 'calculate', relief = 'groove', width = 12)

#Geometry
label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
label2.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
label3.grid( row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10 )
label4.grid( row = 1, column = 4, padx = 10 )
label5.grid( row = 1, column = 5, padx = 10 )
label6.grid( row = 1, column = 6, padx = 10 )
label7.grid( row = 1, column = 7, padx = 10 )
label8.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )
label9.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )
label10.grid( row = 2, column = 3, padx = 10 )
label11.grid( row = 2, column = 4, padx = 10 )
label12.grid( row = 2, column = 5, padx = 10 )
label13.grid( row = 2, column = 6, padx = 10 )
label14.grid( row = 2, column = 7, padx = 10 )
label15.grid( row = 1, column = 8, padx = 10 )
label16.grid( row = 2, column = 8, padx = 10 )
button1.grid( row = 3, column = 4, columnspan = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here. The main issue is that you are attempting to call variables before assigning them. You attempt to use label9 in the first line, despite not defining it until the 18th. This can be fixed by moving the assignment to after label9 has been defined.

(Side Note, the objects with the names label9 to 14 are actually entry boxes. The naming convention should reflect that. I would recommend reading the style guide PEP8)

In the current state, the system will not be able to get the values that a user has typed in, as you are accessing the label object and not the text value within. To get the text value, use the .get() command.

Finally, you need a function to run this as if it is not linked to a function then a) it will not work as intended as the user will not have inputted anything and b) the button will be useless.

This code has the mentioned adjustments (I kept the variable names though) and works

```
mydict = {'good':0.7, 'average':0.5, 'optimal': 1, 'unacceptable': 0, 'major innovation': 1, 'minor innovation': 0.7, 'no innovation': 0.4, '1st lowest': 1, '2nd lowest': 0.7, '3rd lowest': 0.5, '4th lowest': 0.3}


# Widgets:
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
label1 = Label(window, text = 'Bid Number', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label2 = Label(window, text = 'Cost Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label3 = Label(window, text = 'Past Performance', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label4 = Label(window, text = 'Quality Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label5 = Label(window, text = 'Management Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label6 = Label(window, text = 'Innovation Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label7 = Label(window, text = 'Compliance Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label8 = Label(window, text = 'Bid 1' , relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label9 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label10 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label11 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label12 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label13 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label14 = Entry(window, relief = 'groove', width = 12)
label15 = Label(window, text = 'Bid Score', relief = 'groove', width = 16)
label16 = Label(window, text = "", relief = 'groove', width = 12)

def button_function():
    a = float( mydict[label9] ) * float( mydict[label9] ) * float( 
mydict[label9] ) *float( mydict[label10] ) * float( mydict[label11] ) *float( mydict[label12] ) * float( mydict[label13] ) * float( mydict[label13] ) * float( mydict[label14]) 
    b = 1/9
    c = a**b
    label16.config(text=str(c))


button1 = Button(window, text = 'calculate', relief = 'groove', width = 12, command = button_function)



#Geometry
label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
label2.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
label3.grid( row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10 )
label4.grid( row = 1, column = 4, padx = 10 )
label5.grid( row = 1, column = 5, padx = 10 )
label6.grid( row = 1, column = 6, padx = 10 )
label7.grid( row = 1, column = 7, padx = 10 )
label8.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )
label9.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )
label10.grid( row = 2, column = 3, padx = 10 )
label11.grid( row = 2, column = 4, padx = 10 )
label12.grid( row = 2, column = 5, padx = 10 )
label13.grid( row = 2, column = 6, padx = 10 )
label14.grid( row = 2, column = 7, padx = 10 )
label15.grid( row = 1, column = 8, padx = 10 )
label16.grid( row = 2, column = 8, padx = 10 )
button1.grid( row = 3, column = 4, columnspan = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't understand how to use the .get() command to get the text value within.

Comment: The .get() command is used in entry widgets to get the text that current fills it. So instead of having label9, use label9.get()